# changed motherboard, same drive, unclaimed network interface

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

Upgraded motherboard and reused the existing drive with Ubuntu 16.04 installed.  Everything works as expected except the network connection.  lshw states network UNCLAIMED.

To test the motherboard network interface Ubuntu 18.04 was installed on a different drive and the network interface is there and functioning.

Ran lshw -c network for three different configurations, old motherboard/Ubuntu 16.04 drive,
new motherboard/Ubuntu 16.04 drive and new motherboard/Ubuntu 18.04 drive.  Output from lshw commands below.  Driver appears to be the same but the mac address or serial number is different which seems to be the only significant change.

How is the relevant information for an existing install of Ubuntu 16.04 updated so it sees the network interface for a new motherboard?

Old Motherboard/Ubuntu 16.04 Drive:

```
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82566DC-2 Gigabit Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 02
   serial: 00:1c:c0:60:12:b6
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=1.3-0 ip=10.0.1.210 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:30 memory:e3200000-e321ffff memory:e3224000-e3224fff ioport:30e0(size=32)
```

New Motherboard/Ubuntu 16.04 Drive:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   version: 10
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:ab200000-ab21ffff
```

New Motherboard/Ubuntu 18.04 Drive:

```
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: eno1
   version: 10
   serial: 00:d8:61:aa:c2:0b
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:123 memory:ab200000-ab21ffff
```

Comment: That is because network might be unfamiliar with new device MAC, if you're using a router login to your router admin portal via mobile phone if you can't with pc and check if your new device is not restricted.

Comment: Assuming that you're not using netplan, edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` on 16.04. Is your goal to run on 16.04 or 18.04?

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces = auto lo iface lo inet loopback.  For now the the goal is to remain on 16.04.